# NGINX SSL redirects too often

Tags: node.js, loops, ssl, nginx, cloudflare

I am struggling with NGINX and setting up my v-hosts. I'm trying to setup a vhost that redirects HTTP requests to HTTPS and then to my application (when it is 443)

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I am using NGINX 1.10.3.

The nginx.conf looks like that (its mostly the default):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My ServerBlocks / VHosts look like that:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         xxx.com;
    # Prevent MITM
    add_header          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    ssl_certificate     "/etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.com.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.com.key";
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://localhost:2237;
    }
}
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         xxx.com;
    return 301          https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Now the problem is, that either if I am using HTTP or HTTPS it tries to redirect me to HTTPS so I am stucked in an endless Loop of redirects.

I have absolutely no idea where my mistake is.

Every VHost is in a single File. The Application on Port 2237 is a nodeJS Express Server. I am also using Cloudflare (I got my SSL Certificate from them)

Edit:

Output from `curl -I` is:

```
$ curl -I https://example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 06 Oct 2017 19:42:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d827df762e20a4e321b92b34bd15546621507318939; expires=Sat, 06-Oct-18 19:42:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
Location: https://example.com/
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 3a9b1a6a4e4564d5-FRA
```

Comment: Run `nginx -T` and verify there is no additional config which is getting loaded

Comment: @TarunLalwani No, its just that configuration

Comment: Try adding `proxy_redirect http://localhost:2237/ https://$host/;` in your `proxy_pass` block. I think your nodejs app is doing a redirect which might be causing these redirections

Comment: @TarunLalwani I pasted that line under the `proxy_pass` part but still in the location thing and it did not worked :(

Comment: Can you post the output of `curl -v https://<url>`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I added it in the post!

Comment: moved to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156124/discussion-between-dunklestoast-and-tarun-lalwani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use below config

```
server {
listen              80;
server_name         example.com;
add_header          Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
  location / {
    proxy_pass      http://localhost:2237;
    proxy_redirect  http://localhost:2237/ https://$host/;
  }
}
```

Your are using cloudflare SSL and terminating SSL at cloudflare. So you should just be listening on port 80. Your earlier config was redirecting port 80 back to HTTPS and sending the request to Cloudflare which then send to your nginx port 80 and hence creating infinite loop